Memory consumption anomaly - Digital ocean and Laravel
I have a droplet in digital ocean with 3 Laravel projects inside. So far so good, but a few weeks ago the memory consumption has a strange behavior:
Slowly but steadily increases consumption and when it reaches 100% consumption decreases and this loop does so indefinitely. My knowledge on server issues is quite basic, can someone guide me to find where the fault is?

Your question has very little to go on. Please do some research and edit your question with details.  https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask     How is this a problem for your users?  What OS distro and version?  If this is Linux, include  the contents of /proc/pressure/memory  and  /proc/meminfo   under load.
